# How to replace a value of variable in one file using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, replace

I have one Makefile in which I want to change/replace the value of a variable during runtime with bash script.

SUBDIRS = common database communication

I want to replace this value of SUBDIRS with -

```
 protocols
```

How can i replace it using shell script?

I tried

```
  sed 's/\(SUBDIRS =\).*/\protocols/' Makefile
```

But this is not working properly. Please suggest.

Comment: check the update using `awk` in following answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/(SUBDIRS = ).*/\1protocols/' Makefile
SUBDIRS = protocols
```

Using back refrencing, part of the string is captured inside `(` and `)` and called captured groups. Later each captured group can be called in as `\1` ,`\2` etc. You can capture upto 9 capture groups.

If there is chance of multi-line text, you can use `awk`:

Sample input with multi-lines:

```
echo "$y"
SUBDIRS = common database communication
                   ola ola ola
                   bla bla bla


echo "$y" |awk -v RS="\n\n"  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}{$2="protocols"}1'
SUBDIRS =protocols
```

Comment: thnx but I am not able to use it. Can you look at my complete exact scenarios posted in new question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881278/how-to-replace-a-value-of-variable-in-one-file-from-text-file-using-bash-script

how I can read variable from makefile and then use awk with it.