# How to replace a value of variable in one file from text file using bash script?

Tags: bash, sed

I have one Makefile in which I want to change/replace the value of a variable during runtime with bash script.

Makefile content:-

```
  SUBDIRS = common alarm coders crypto communication conup database \
            dynamicProtocols dynamethods dynamic TTStorage tables \
            jobManager logManager processManager \
            collection processing distribution mediationManager adaptations tools performanceMonitor \
            cli
```

Now I want this SUBDIRS value to be replaced with content of my text file.

Text file content:-

```
         database
         common
         jobManager
         coders
         process
```

This text file content may vary from 1-20 words.

Now as suggested in another thread, we used below solution for single word:-

```
        sed -r 's/(SUBDIRS = ).*/\1protocols/' Makefile
```

But this only replaces first line with 'protocols'. Generated output is:-

```
      SUBDIRS = protocols
                dynamicProtocols dynamethods dynamic TTStorage tables \
                jobManager logManager processManager \
                collection processing distribution mediationManager adaptations tools performanceMonitor \
                cli
```

While desired output is:-

```
           SUBDIRS = protocols
```

Now, we want to read all contents of text file and assign to SUBDIRS. Shown below:

```
     SUBDIRS = database common jobManager coders process
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed -z -e 's/\n//g' -e "s/\(SUBDIRS = \).*/\1$(tr '\n' ' ' < words)\n/;" Makefile
```

- `words` is a filename containing *from 1-20 words*
- `-z` - treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte
- `s/\n//g` - removing newlines in the `Makefile`
- `$(tr '\n' ' ' < words)` - translating newlines into spaces in the `words` file

The output:

```
SUBDIRS = database common jobManager coders process
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is working upto some extent but here it displays below when I run this command and does not save changes in original Makefile. 
Output coming: It is making our complete makefile new lines go away.

    ifeq ($(UNAME_SYSTEM), SunOS)SUBDIRS = common database communication process

and it exits after replacing at first occurance. I applied 'g' also in end but not works.

Comment: @user3256114, *It is making our complete makefile new lines go away* - why it should be an issue if you have posted the complete `Makefile` content?

Comment: You will need to add -i to actually update the Makefile

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest we dont want to modify our whole Makefile. Make builds won't work like that. We only want a variable inside a Makefile to be repalced with new values.
So I cannot globally replace newlines with spaces. Also, it exits as soon as first occuraance of variable is replaced and Makefile is incomplete.